# Simple composition of functions in Scala

Tags: scala, function-composition, scalastyle

I have a simplified version of my code. What would be clear, what I want conceptually:

```
def heavyCalcMul: Int => Int = i => i * 2
def heavyCalcDiv: Int => Int = i => i / 2
def heavyCalcPls: Int => Int = i => i + 2
```

and I use it like this:

```
val x = 2
val midResult = heavyCalcMul(x)
val result = heavyCalcDiv(midResult) + heavyCalcPls(midResult)
```

but I want rewrite this code in this style:

```
val x = 2
val result = heavyCalcMul(x) { midResult: Int =>
  heavyCalcDiv(midResult) + heavyCalcPls(midResult)
}
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `andThen`:

```
val calc = heavyCalcMul
  .andThen(mid => 
     heavyCalcDiv(mid) + heavyCalcPls(mid)
  )

val result2 = calc(x)
```

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/3U6qM4g/0)

Comment: This works:)  thanks! I tried too much around "=>" and make it without third def/val.